# Concatenar archivos

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Necesito implementar código en shell que sea capaz de concatenar varios archivos .txt en un solo archivo como si fuera una escritura única en este fichero. Además se debe identificar cuando se agregue un nuevo txt y sea capaz de concatenarlo en el mismo archivo.
Lo que tengo es esto:

```
cat *.txt > temperaturas.txt
```

Comment: " Además se debe identificar cuando se agregue un nuevo txt" , a que te refieres ? como se identificaría?

Comment: En una ruta específica van a haber varios .txt que se deben concatenar en uno solo, y cada vez que se agregue uno nuevo en esa ruta, el shell deberia poder identificar el nuevo que se agregó, y concatenarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #carpeta y archivo de concatenaciones
    DIRECTORY="./html/"
    OUTPUT="./output.txt"
    IGNORE="PDF|pdf|exe|EXE"

    #archivo de estado
    FILES="./files.txt"

    #hacemos un for en base a los archivos en la carpeta
    for i in $(/bin/ls $DIRECTORY | grep -Ev $IGNORE);
    do
     # validamos que sea un archivo y sea legible
     if [[ -r DIRECTORY/$i ]]; then # puede ser cambiado -r por -f solo para que valide que es un archivo
        #validamos que el archivo de resultados exista!
         if [[ ! -f $FILES ]]; then
            # si no existe se le concatena el primer resultado y se le agrega a la lista
echo "[+] el archivo $i se va a concatenar a $OUTPUT";
             echo $i >> $FILES;
             cat $i >> $OUTPUT;
         fi
        # validamos si los archivos en carpeta existan en el documento de archivos listados
        # si no existe lo agregamos
         if [[ $(cat $FILES | grep $i | grep -v "grep" )  == "" ]]; then
            echo "[+] el archivo $i se va a concatenar a $OUTPUT";
            # agregamos el nuevo archivo a nuestra lista
            echo DIRECTORY/$i >> $FILES
            # agregamos el nuevo contendido al archivo de salida
            cat DIRECTORY/$i >> $OUTPUT
         fi
     else
        echo "[-] El archivo $i no se puede leer"
     fi
    done
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes poner un archivo con un while y que realice la concatenación.

Algo por este estilo

```
#!/bin/bash

RUTA="./ruta"  # Esta es una carpeta donde estarán los archivos a concatenar.
ARCHIVO_CONDENSADO="./archivo_condensado"

INTERVALO="3s" #intervalo de tiempo en el formato que acepta el comando sleep

while :
do
    cat "$RUTA"/*.txt > "$ARCHIVO_CONDENSADO"
    sleep "$INTERVALO"
done
```

Y ya fuera del script, y dándole los permisos de ejecución, simplemente corres.

```
$ nohup ./script &
```

Y se concatenarán los archivos a uno cada 3 segundos sobre escribiendo el archivo "archivo_condensado" que es donde se almacenarán todos los archivos concatenados. A pesar de que es muy poco tiempo tiene el "potencial" de que, a diferencia de un cronjob, puede correrse en fracciones de minutos, ya que un cronjob tiene al minuto como unidad mínima. En ese script puedes cambiar el valor de la variable intervalo siguiendo el formato que pide el comando `sleep` (puedes revisar en `man sleep`)
El problema a mi script es que, desde mis pocos años de desarrollador, no le veo sentido a su existencia jaja ;) a menos que sea un ejercicio personal. Esto se podría sustituir por una instrucción de un cronjob.

```
$ crontab -e
```

Luego te pedirá que edites un archivo y pondrás algo de este estilo:

```
* * * * * cat /ruta/a/tu/carpeta/*.txt > /ruta/a/tu/archivo
```

Guardas ese archivo que te haga editar el comando `crontab -e` y con eso se instala una tarea que se ejecutará cada minuto la que consistirá en concatenar todos los archivos de una carpeta a otro archivo cada minuto, todos los días de cada mes de cada año. Aunque a eso tampoco le veo sentido porque concatenas... ¿Y luego qué?, tal vez prefieras hacer un backup con `tar` y, cada cierto tiempo, subirlo a una base de datos o almacenarlo en el servidor o algo más que sobre escribir archivos de uno u otro tipo.

Si quieres algo que revise y opere según los cambios del contenido de la carpeta o de los archivos, habría que crear una clase de *journaling*. Y si, con estas dos opciones anteriormente planteadas, no es suficiente, no dudes en comentar.

**Nota**: no he corrido ninguna de las opciones que plantee, lo escribí al vuelo así que siéntete libre de comentar si no te funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo usando `type`:

```
type "C:\<Directorio conteniendo archivos>\*.txt" > temperaturas.txt
```

de esta forma se anexara al archivo `temperaturas.txt` el contenido de todos los archivos del directorio.